# Freemat 4.2 package for Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: package-management, freemat

Any chance to have the Freemat 4.2 package for Ubuntu 20.04. I can only find it as rpm package (for Fedora for example). It was available in previous release of Ubuntu. I really need this programs for mechanical engineering calculations.

Comment: Freemat is not developed anymore. Use Octave or Scilab instead. They all try to be as much MATLAB compatible as possible, and are actively developed (among the two, Octave is more compatible with MATLAB).

Answer (score 1):

Unofficial snap is available at https://snapcraft.io/freemat-unofficial. To install it open the terminal and type:

```
sudo snap install freemat-unofficial
```

Answer (score 0):

Sorry: Freemat was dropped from Debian and Ubuntu in 2019 as abandoned/unmaintained upstream. The last release was 2013.

Abandoned means that the upstream developers no longer respond to bug reports or feature requests.

- Freemat can be re-added if a new upstream developer or maintainer steps forward and adopts/forks the code.
- You can download the 19.10 package from http://packages.ubuntu.com and try to get apt to install it: `sudo apt install /path/to/package_name.deb`

Answer (score 0):

You have to download FreeMat package with dependency manually from Ubuntu 18.04 LTS release. The main problem here is Qt4 removal from 20.04 LTS, so we need to get it first from special [third-party PPA](https://launchpad.net/%7Erock-core/+archive/ubuntu/qt4).

The complete reproducible method is below:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:rock-core/qt4
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install libqt4-dev qt4-qmake qt4-dev-tools

cd ~/Downloads
wget http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/libf/libffi/libffi6_3.2.1-8_amd64.deb
wget http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/f/freemat/freemat_4.2+dfsg1-6_amd64.deb
wget http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/f/freemat/freemat-data_4.2+dfsg1-6_all.deb
wget http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/f/freemat/freemat-help_4.2+dfsg1-6_all.deb

sudo apt-get install ./libffi6_3.2.1-8_amd64.deb ./freemat_4.2+dfsg1-6_amd64.deb ./freemat-data_4.2+dfsg1-6_all.deb ./freemat-help_4.2+dfsg1-6_all.deb
```

Then launch FreeMat and use it was planned.